# Store an uploaded file from HTML form into a variable - PHP

Tags: php, file-upload, forms, http-post

User upload a file via form. I am trying to store the file in a variable in php.

HTML code:

```
<form class="generalForm" action="save.php" method="POST">
    <label class="headLabel">DODAJ</label>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input class="inputTextSub" id="naziv" name="naziv" placeholder="naziv" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'naziv'" type="text">
    <br>
    <br>
    <input class="inputTextSub" id="opis" name="opis" placeholder="opis" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'naziv'" type="text">
    <br>
    <br>
    <input class="inputTextSub" id="datumz" name="datumz" type="date">
    <br>
    <br>
    <input class="inputTextSub" id="datumk" name="datumk" type="date">
    <br>
    <br>
    <label class="inputTextSub">prioriteta</label>
    <select class="inputSelSub" id="pr" name="pr">
        <option value=1>1</option>
        <option value=2>2</option></select>
    <br>
    <br>
    <label class="inputTextSub">format</label>
    <select class="inputSelSub" id="format" name="format">
        <option value=1>A3</option>
        <option value=2>A4</option></select>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="file" name="inputfile" id="file" class="inputfile" />
    <br>
    <br>
    <input class="button" style="margin-top:2em;" name="save" type="submit" value=" shrani ">
</from>
```

PHP code:

```
if(isset($_POST['save'])){
   $naziv = $_POST['naziv'];
   $opis = $_POST['opis'];
   $datumz = $_POST['datumz'];
   $datumk = $_POST['datumk'];
   $pr = $_POST['pr'];
   $format = $_POST['format'];
   $file = file_get_contents($_FILES['inputfile']['tmp_name']); //error occurs here!
   $modId = $_SESSION['mod_id'];
   $stmt = $GLOBALS['conn']->prepare(
   "INSERT INTO `deska`(`mod_id`, `naziv`, `opis`, `datumz`, `datumk`, 
   `prioriteta`, `slika`, `tip`, `datumSpremembe`) 
   VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,CURRENT_DATE)"
   );
   if(!$stmt->bind_param("mod_id",$modId) ||
      !$stmt->bind_param("naziv",$naziv) ||
      !$stmt->bind_param("opis",$opis) ||
      !$stmt->bind_param("datumz",$datumz) ||
      !$stmt->bind_param("datumk",$datumk) ||
      !$stmt->bind_param("prioriteta",$pr) ||
      !$stmt->bind_param("slika",$file) ||
      !$stmt->bind_param("tip",$format)){
          die("Opa, nekaj je šlo narobe! (add)");
      }
   if(!$stmt->execute()){
       die("Opa, nekaj je šlo narobe! (addEx)");
   }
   $stmt->close();    
}
```

The errors are:

> Notice: Undefined index: input file in
>       C:\xampp\htdocs\mod\sub\save.php on line 10
>
> Warning: file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty in
>           C:\xampp\htdocs\mod\sub\save.php on line 10

I would really appreciate any help that you guys can provide.

Comment: You need to use `move_uploaded_file()` (as stated in the docs) before you get the contents of the file.

Comment: Also `enctype` attribute of the form required.

Comment: Change </from> to </form>

Answer (score 0):

Buddy you had missed one attribute in form tag **enctype="multipart/form-data"** just add that because for files we have to add this attribute